# AWS AutoScale Strategy for AutoScaling group for a new web site

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, aws-auto-scaling

If we have a site we have no data on its pattern traffic because it has never been online, and for the first time, we will put it online.

We are confident that the website will have a significant, increase in usage in the first 2 to 4 months.

What will be the best AutoScaling Strategy for the WebServers and Application Servers?

Let's imagine we are using EC2 instances for both web and app servers.

Thanks

Comment: " a site we have no data on " - what does it mean? A static website?

Comment: sounds like static website to me, too. S3+CF ftw!

Comment: @Marcin, Just fixed the description of the problem.